# Injecting .cs file into msbuild works fine except the Intellisense (VS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, intellisense, msbuild-task, csproj

This is what i am trying to do, but so far been unsuccessful. I have a WPF Project with some xaml classes. I have a msbuild task that creates partial classes with the same name as xaml classes but with some extra properties. The partial classes gets created properly and it builds fine too. However the newly created properties do not show up on the Intellisense in VS2010. I am also using Resharper.

I have imported my target in the original .csproj file. the original file is pasted at the end of the question.

```
<Import Project="..\XamlModifyTask\bin\Debug\TXamlModifyTask.csproj" />
```

And this is how the TXamlModifyTask.csproj looks like

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="XamlModifyTask.dll" TaskName="XamlModifyTask"/>
<!--PropertyGroup>
    <ResolveReferencesDependsOn>XamlModify;$(ResolveReferencesDependsOn)</ResolveReferencesDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup-->
<PropertyGroup>
    <CompileDependsOn>XamlModify;$(CompileDependsOn)</CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <SettingsGenerated Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)**\*.test.cs"></SettingsGenerated>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="XamlModify">
<XamlModifyTask Files="@(Page)" OutputPath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"></XamlModifyTask>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="@(SettingsGenerated)"></Compile>
        <FileWrites Include="@(SettingsGenerated)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I have even tried using BeforeCompile/BeforeBuild events. but it does not work. Am i doing something wrong here.

This is the original project file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<UsingTask TaskName="JPMorgan.Build.XamlModifyTask" AssemblyFile="H:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\JPMorgan.Build.dll" />
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
<ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ProjectGuid>{55A24932-DA31-4837-9E1E-9E69C34BFB5F}</ProjectGuid>
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>WpfApplication1</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>WpfApplication1</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Xaml">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
<Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
<Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</ApplicationDefinition>
<Compile Include="View\Window1.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Window1.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Window2.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Window2.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Window4.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Window4.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
<Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
<Page Include="View\Window1.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
<Page Include="Window2.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
<Page Include="Window3.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
<Compile Include="Window3.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Window3.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Page Include="Window4.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
  <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
</Compile>
<EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
<None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
  <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
<AppDesigner Include="Properties\" />
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="..\XamlModifyTask\bin\Debug\TXamlModifyTask.csproj" />

<!--Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="@(SettingsGenerated)"></Compile>
  <FileWrites Include="@(SettingsGenerated)"/>
</ItemGroup>
</Target-->
<!--Target Name="AfterBuild">
</Target-->
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you generate [XML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx) and make it available for Visual Studio?

Comment: Isn't XML Documentation more for the summary associated with each method to be displayed in the Intellisense ?

Comment: Intellisense problems can be worked around as I describe at [this link](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/1711#issuecomment-419590124).

Comment: Full solution: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21024#issuecomment-421511042